# What does the addition mean in function(1,a+2) if a is an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I was looking at this piece of code and I'm not sure what the addition means if "a" is an array.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

function(1, a+2);
return 0;}
```

Assume the function is already created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an expression (except when used with sizeof or &), an array name is a pointer to the first element in the array. So `a+2` is "pointer arithmetic" on that pointer, and results in a pointer to the element at offset 2. It is equivalent to `&a[2]`.

Comment: it won't let me until after 10 minutes has passed.

Comment: It's important to note here that an array is NOT a pointer, and you shouldn't always treat it as one. The author is correct that an array will readily default to a pointer in an expression, but the two are not always interchangeable. Look here for a more thorough explanation: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html